# How to do a basic query on yahoo search engine using Python without using any yahoo api?

Tags: python

I want to do a basic query on yahoo search engine from a python script using Beautiful Soup and urllib. I've done the same for Google which was rather easy but Yahoo is proving to be a bit difficult. A minimal example script of a query to yahoo search engine would help. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you could show your google script as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, avoid `urllib` - use [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) instead, it's a much saner interface.

Then, all links in the returned page have the class `yschttl` and an ID following the scheme `link-1`, `link-2` and so on. That you can use with beautiful soup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=%s"
query = "python"
r = requests.get(url % query) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "yschttl"})

for link in soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "yschttl"}):
    print "%s (%s)" %(link.text, link.get('href'))
```

Gives us

> ```
> Python Programming Language – Official Website (http://www.python.org/)
> Python - Image Results (http://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images?_adv_prop=image&va=python)
> Python (programming language) - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language))
> ```

and more.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but as far as I can tell, it is missing a line which assigns the value to `soup`. Something like `soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text)`

Comment: This appears to be out of date. It is not returning any results

Comment: You can use, soup =  BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

Answer (score 1):

Amending Manuel's code to work:

```
url = "http://api.search.yahoo.com/search?p=%s"
query = 'Python'
r = requests.get(url % query) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features = "lxml")
soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "fz-ms lh-1_43x"})

for link in soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "fz-ms lh-1_43x"}):
    print(link.text)
    # print(link.text, link.get('href'))
    print('---------------------------------------------------')
```